# MYSQL ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2),

Tags: mysql

````
```Rajas-MacBook-Air:~ rajas$ mysql -u root -p
   Enter password: 
   ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
   Rajas-MacBook-Air:~ rajas$ sudo mysql.server start
   Password:
   Starting MySQL
   ... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/Rajas-MacBook-Air.local.pid).
````

I did so much workaround but could not solve...
Please someone can suggest me some solution.

OS: mac 10.12
mysql@5.7.32

Comment: sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql /usr/local/var/mysql

Comment: Did the same and relaunched the terminal. Still same error..
```ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)```

Comment: And doing ```mysqld stop ``` and 
```brew services start mysql ``` that gives ```Error: Formula `mysql` is not installed.```

Comment: brew install mysql?

Comment: That too I have done, ```brew reinstall mysql```

Comment: get into the directory of your mysql installation, in may be  /usr/local/mysql/bin then start the mysql server: sudo ./mysqld_safe.  Now you should be able to connect to your mysql client